# problema al cargar lista recyclerview con firebaseui

Tags: java, android, firebase, recyclerview

soy muy nueva en esto de desarrollar aplicaciones, estoy haciendo esta app en donde tengo que guardar unos datos en la nube, estoy usando firebaseui con recyclerview para ello. Pude subir los datos pero al momento de cargar la lista mi app se cierra.Aqui les dejo el codigo:

```
package com.code.plantas;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Entity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import java.io.File;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import com.code.plantas.R;

public class NewPlant extends AppCompatActivity{

private ImageView imagen;
private EditText nomb,nomc,fam,hoj,tall,flo;
private String key;
private Button foto,guardar;

private static final FirebaseDatabase DATABASE= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
private static final FirebaseStorage STORAGE =FirebaseStorage.getInstance();


  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_plant);

    nomb=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.nom);
    nomc=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.nomc);
    fam=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.familia);
    hoj=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.hojas);
    tall=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.tallo);
    flo=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.flores);


    guardar=(Button)findViewById(R.id.guardar) ;
    foto=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnFoto);
     guardar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Plant p = new Plant(nomb.getText().toString(),nomc.getText().toString(),fam.getText().toString(),hoj.getText().toString(),tall.getText().toString(),flo.getText().toString());
                DATABASE.getReference().push().setValue(p);

            //CUANDO SE GUARDE
            nomb.setText("");
            nomc.setText("");
            fam.setText("");
            hoj.setText("");
            tall.setText("");
            flo.setText("");

            Toast.makeText(NewPlant.this,"Done",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}
}
```

Mi modelo de datos:

```
public class Plant {
private String name;
private String cname;
private String familia;
private String hojas;
private String tallo;
private String flores;

public Plant() {
}

public Plant(String name, String cname, String familia, String hojas, String tallo, String flores) {
    this.name = name;
    this.cname = cname;
    this.familia = familia;
    this.hojas = hojas;
    this.tallo = tallo;
    this.flores = flores;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getCname() {
    return cname;
}

public void setCname(String cname) {
    this.cname = cname;
}

public String getFamilia() {
    return familia;
}

public void setFamilia(String familia) {
    this.familia = familia;
}

public String getHojas() {
    return hojas;
}

public void setHojas(String hojas) {
    this.hojas = hojas;
}

public String getTallo() {
    return tallo;
}

public void setTallo(String tallo) {
    this.tallo = tallo;
}

public String getFlores() {
    return flores;
}

public void setFlores(String flores) {
    this.flores = flores;
}
}
```

Mi Adaptador:

```
package com.code.plantas;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;


public class PlantList extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.plant_list);

    RecyclerView recyclerView= (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.rv);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(PlantList.this));
    DatabaseReference ref= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Plant,PlantHolder>adapter=new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Plant, PlantHolder>(Plant.class,R.layout.plant_list,PlantHolder.class,ref) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(PlantHolder viewHolder, Plant model, int position) {
           viewHolder.setName(model.getName());

        }
    };

recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

}

Holder:

```
package com.code.plantas;

import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class PlantHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
public final TextView nombre;

public PlantHolder(View itemView){
    super (itemView);
nombre=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.nname);

}


public void setName(String name) {
    nombre.setText(name);
}
}
```

El Manifest:

El Layout del Recyclerview:


       
       

      


     

El codigo para cada fila:

       
       



    

        

        

            


        
    



La actividad donde se escriben los datos:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/nom"
    android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:hint="Nombre" />

<Button
    android:text="@string/foto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/btnFoto"
    android:layout_above="@+id/guardar"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_below="@+id/nomc"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:id="@+id/familia"
    android:hint="@string/familia" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_below="@+id/hojas"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:id="@+id/tallo"
    android:hint="Tallo" />

<Button
    android:text="@string/guardar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/guardar"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/hojas"
    android:hint="Hojas"
    android:layout_below="@+id/familia"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/flores"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tallo"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:hint="Flores" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
    android:id="@+id/nomc"
    android:hint="Nombre Cientifico"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/nom"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

   </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: que mensaje obtienes en el log cuando se cierra?

Comment: no hay nada en el logcat, tampoco hay error en el codigo. Creo ke el problema eseta en el Holder, en los setters